# Create an image from source image using Contour points in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have to find squares in an image and then create a separate image of the detected square. So far, i am able to detect the square and get its contour in terms of four points.

**Problem:** When i create the image using ROI, i am getting the background also where the square is not present. I want to remove that area and want to keep only the area related to square.

Comment: See the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093174/copying-non-rectangular-roi-opencv/22093257#22093257

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a mask!

Create a black and white single-channel image (CV_U8C1). The white part is the desired area (your region of interest, ROI) from the original image.

The vector "ROI_Vertices" contains the vertices of the ROI. Fit a polygon around it (ROI_Poly), then fill it with white.

Afterwards use [CopyTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=copy#mat-copyto) to subtract your ROI from the image.

```
// ROI by creating mask for your trapecoid
// Create black image with the same size as the original    
Mat mask = cvCreateMat(480, 640, CV_8UC1); 
for(int i=0; i<mask.cols; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<mask.rows; j++)
        mask.at<uchar>(Point(i,j)) = 0;

// Create Polygon from vertices
vector<Point> ROI_Poly;
approxPolyDP(ROI_Vertices, ROI_Poly, 1.0, true);

// Fill polygon white
fillConvexPoly(mask, &ROI_Poly[0], ROI_Poly.size(), 255, 8, 0);                 

// Create new image for result storage
Mat resImage = cvCreateMat(480, 640, CV_8UC3);

// Cut out ROI and store it in resImage 
image->copyTo(resImage, mask);
```

Thanks to [this guy](http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/5) for providing me with all the information i needed two weeks ago, when i had the same problem!

Comment: `Mat mask = Mat::zeros(480, 640, CV_8UC1);`
should do the same as the first 4 lines, but i can't test it atm