# Opencv crop a parallelogram image in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am using Python and Opencv. I am now doing a license-plate recognition project. I can now recognize the plate like this:

[image]

And I got an "array" like this :

```
[[[542 796]]

 [[965 883]]

 [[547 884]]
   
 [[966 795]]]
```

The problem is: How can I crop out the bound region with these coordinates?

As the four corrdinates are permuted and it is not a rectangle, so I dont know how I can crop this out.

Comment: Is there any fast way to find the upper-left point coordinates?

Comment: If your script always returns the array in the same way, then it is the fixed-index element of it. How are your axes defined? If x = 0 and y = 0 is the top-left corner of an image, then the point you are looking for is the first one in the array.

Comment: do you want to warp the parallelogram to get a rectangle (wich might distort the interior of the parallelogram), or do you want to crop a rectangle around the parallelogram (and so get some background in your cropped image)? The latter is easily achieved by cv::boundingBox function.

Answer (score 0):

You can crop the inner rectangle or outer bounding rectangle. Let the four co-ordinates be:-

(x1,y1),     (x2,y2)

(x3,y3),   (x4,y4)

Assuming, you are interested in outer bounding rectangle, so that no letter is segmented, you can do simple cropping using below ROI.

```
int topLeftX = min(x1,x3);
int topLeftY = min(y1, y2);
int width = max(x2, x4) - topLeftX;
int height = max(y3, y4) - topLeftY;
cv::Rect outerRoi(topLeftX, topLeftY, width, height);
cv::Mat roiImage = image(outerRoi); //Note that this will not create a deep copy
```

If interested in largest rectangle which fits the trapezium from inside, you should swap min with max and vice-versa.

If you want a trapezium like roi, you should create a mask image. For further directions,, see [copying non-rectangular roi opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093174/copying-non-rectangular-roi-opencv)