# BoofCV (Android): How to use commercial-free alternatives to Surf

Tags: java, android, opencv, feature-detection, boofcv

I recently came across the boofcv project and it is really amazing. I like it because it is very easy to use. I adjusted this example: http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Associate_Interest_Points to work on android. But this feature uses Surf and as far as I know the version of surf included in BoofCV is not free for commercial purposes. BRISK, ORB, etc. may work as well but I don't know how to implement them.

Two questions:
Is SURF free in combination with boofcv?
*and*
If not: How can I modify the example code to work with a free-for-commercial-use Feature Matcher/Descriptor/Extractor?

(BoofCV seems to be the best choice for beginners that are completely new to Computer Vision and Android development, doesn't it?)

Comment: First, since BoofCV is not commercial, why are trying it for commercial purpose(research and academic purpose are though valid). Second, try AKAZE instead of SURF. See here :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/39945374/1874627 . In this case, I found the registration to work flawlessly and better than SURF.

Comment: I actually wrote that "SURF" implementation.  Not 100% sure if it's covered by the SURF patent because to make it run fast/stable I changed a lot of the algorithm but designed it to behave in the same way.  Wrote a [paper](http://boofcv.org/techreports/2013_Abeles_SpeedingUpSURF_ISVC.pdf) about the modifications even.  BTW that's not legal advice.  I have no idea so I've left it ambiguous.

Comment: OpenCV's implementation of SURF has given SURF a bad name.  Maybe they've fixed it but as of 3 years ago it was partially broken and many papers were published claiming superior performance when they actually had inferior performance to the original SURF implementation.  That paper also covers that issue.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. That helped me.